# SwiftUI Firestore fetch user data after log in

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swiftui

After a successful log in from Firestore I want to call my `/users` table to fetch additional data for this user. Like rating, savedItems and other stuff like that.

What I have done is that I have created an `UserEnvironmentObject` which as the name says it's an `EnvironmentObject`. I'm storing here the `User` which I get back from Firestore and also a `ClientViewModel`

ClientViewModel is used also for ex: when a user request the profile of another user, thats why I went with this approach, to reuse my existing ClientViewModel. However the issue is that I do not feel it's ok to have an ObservableObject inside an EnvironmentObject. Is there A better way to achieve this ?

```
class UserEnvironmentObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user: User?
    @Published var clientViewModel: ClientViewModel?
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

    func listen() {
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
            self.user = user

            self.firestoreService.fetchDocument(documentReference: documentReference) { (result: Result<Client, Error>) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let client):
                    let clientViewModel = ClientViewModel(client: client)
                    self.savedItems = client.savedItems
                    self.rating = clientViewModel.rating
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        })
    }
}


class ClientViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var client: Client?
    var firestoreService: FirestoreService = FirestoreService()

    init(client: Client?) {
        self.client = client
    }

    var rating: String {
        guard let ratings = client?.ratings else { return "5.0" }
        return Double(ratings.reduce(0, +) / ratings.count).roundToDecimal(1).description
    }

    func loadClient(documentReference: DocumentReference?) {
        if let documentReference = documentReference {
            firestoreService.fetchDocument(documentReference: documentReference) { (result: Result<Client, Error>) in
                switch result {
                case .success(let client):
                    self.client = client
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are your concerns about having an ObservableObject in environmentObject? Implementing a Redux like pattern requires the same approach, and I have been doing that on my projects. https://tech.mercari.com/entry/2019/12/11/150000

One small gotcha for this situation, all swiftUI views are supposed to have access to environment objects, however, currently Sheet views do not. to fix this you pass the environment object explicitly like this:

```
@EnvironmentObject var store: AppStore

.sheet(isPresented: $someBoolean, content: { SomeView().environmentObject(self.store)})
```